# What's wrong with this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, boolean-logic

I have `listA=[[0,1],[1,2]]`, and `listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3],[0,2,4]]`.
I want to find all elements b from listB such that b⊆a doesn't hold and a⊆b doesn't hold for all elements a from listA. Put it another way, my desired output is: `listC=[[0,2,3],[0,2,4]]`.

I tried the following codes:

```
import numpy as np

listA=[[0,1],[1,2]]
listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3],[0,2,4]]

listC=[b for b in listB if (((not set(a).issubset(set(b))) and (not set(b).issubset(set(a)))) for a in listA)]
print(listC)
```

However, the output is `[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3],[0,2,4]]`, which is not what I want. My guess is that something is wrong in the if part of the list comprehension. How could it be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is a little wonky. You want the elements in `listB` that are not superset (or subset) of any element in `listA`. So if you replace

```
(((not set(a).issubset(set(b))) and (not set(b).issubset(set(a)))) for a in listA)
```

with

```
any(set(a).issubset(b) or set(b).issubset(a) for a in listA)
```

it will work as expected.

```
listC = [b for b in listB if not any(set(a).issubset(b) or set(b).issubset(a) for a in listA)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4]]
```